# How to structure Gradle builds to allow building interdependent libraries

Tags: gradle

I built a small little test project to see if Gradle would solve this problem we currently have with Maven. We have 200 little libraries, all of them Maven projects, whenever you do a clean checkout, you have to `mvn install` each of them individually

To simulate such a scenario, i've created 4 modules:

```
root
 - jvaas-gson
 - jvaas-jackson
 - jvaas-json
 - jvaas-provider
```

Both `jvaas-gson` and `jvaas-jackson` depends on `jvaas-json` and `jvaas-provider`. `jvaas-json` only depends on `jvaas-provider`.
If some external application wants to include JSON capabilities, they should only have to include `jvaas-gson` or `jvaas-jackson` which uses an interface in `jvaas-json` (as i said, this is just experimenting with it, actual use-case would be to switch out email providers, payment providers etc only having to change a line in the Gradle build script)

In `jvaas-provider` i have a `settings.gradle.kts`

```
rootProject.name = "jvaas-provider"
```

and a `build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.getKotlinPluginVersion

group = "io.jvaas"
version = "1.3.0"

plugins {
    `maven-publish`
    kotlin("jvm") version("1.3.10")
    id("org.jetbrains.dokka") version "0.9.16"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib", getKotlinPluginVersion()))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1")
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

In `jvaas-json` i'm trying to access one of the classes in `jvaas-provider`, so i've added it to the `settings.gradle.kts`

```
rootProject.name = "jvaas-json"

include("jvaas-provider")
```

and the `build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.getKotlinPluginVersion

group = "io.jvaas"
version = "1.3.0"

plugins {
    `maven-publish`
    kotlin("jvm") version("1.3.10")
    id("org.jetbrains.dokka") version "0.9.16"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib", getKotlinPluginVersion()))
    implementation(group = "io.jvaas", name = "jvaas-provider", version = "$version")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1")
}
```

Inside `jvaas-json`, i'm trying access one of the classes i created inside `jvaas-provider`, but it's not resolving.

Without having to manually install `jvaas-provider` in the local maven repo (`mvn install`), is it possible to use it as a dependency inside `jvaas-json`? If so, what should i be changing in my Gradle build scripts and Settings files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul on the Kotlin Slack just answered my question just before i could hit Post on my StackOverflow question, so posting this as QA-style, maybe it'll help somebody else in the future.

Gradle has something called [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) which allows you to include other projects / libraries inside your project without having to install them to a local maven repo first.

For the above example to work with composite builds, all i had to do was change something in the `settings.gradle.kts` file:

```
rootProject.name = "jvaas-json"

includeBuild("../jvaas-provider")
```